# Linkage between 2 cells of 2 different JTables if their values are equal

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have 2 tables which are holding the values stated respectively:

```
L1 = [“one”,”two”,”three”]
L2 = [“one”,”three”,”two”]
```

I want to add a link between the 2 tables for
each equivalent string. The links need to be dynamic and move as you scroll down either of the tables. The 2 tables are in the same panel.

Is there any predefined methods for this or any ideas how to do this?

Comment: *"Is there any predefined methods for this.."* No. Why would you expect an 'out of the box' solution for such a specialized requirement? *"..or any ideas how to do this?"* This question is probably 'too broad' as is, but for the rendering, you might consider using a [layered pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely no "out of the box " way to do this, but I'd suggest the following.

1) Move the panel that your two tables are on to be in a JLayeredPane.

2) Add another panel to the JLayeredPane, above the panel with the tables, so your component hierarchy should look like this:

```
JLayeredPane
|---JPanel - the new top panel
|---JPanel - your original panel
   |---JTable
   |---JTable
```

3) Make the new top panel non-opaque, so it's see through, and you can see your tables.

4) Override the paintComponent(Graphics g) method of this new top-most panel. If you use the below example, you can confirm that everything so far is OK, so you should see a diagonal red line across all your tables:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

5) If you do the above and can see the red line, everything is ready for the next step.

6) Remove the two lines from the paintComponent function and add logic to draw the lines you require. For example:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);

    for (int row1=0; row1<table1.getRowCount(); row1++) {

        //look up value and bounds of the row in table 1
        Object value1 = table1.getValueAt(row1, 0);
        Rectangle r1 = table1.getCellRect(row1, 0, true);

        //find the corresponding row number in table 2
        for (int row2=0; row2<table2.getRowCount(); row2++) {
            Object value2 = table2.getValueAt(row2, 0);
            if (value2.equals(value1)) {

                Rectangle r2 = table2.getCellRect(row2, 0, true);

                //convert both points to be the in the component space of this panel
                Point p1 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(table1, r1.getLocation(), this);
                Point p2 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(table2, r2.getLocation(), this);

                //and draw the line
                g.drawLine(r1.x, r1.y, r2.x, r2.y);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE - the above example is based on the assumption that your two tables only have one column each, and that you're drawing between the top left of each cell. If there are multiple columns, then change the zeros to be whatever column you want to compare. And you'll probably want to adjust the points to draw from the middle right of cells in the left-hand table to the middle left of cells in the right-hand table.